# unable to create a react app using "create-react-app" nvm is not compatible with the npm config

Tags: reactjs

recently updated node  and yarn
But now I get an error when running create-react app
package.json is generated then deleted
please help

Tried reinstalling node and npm even yarn but still same outcome please help

Answer (score 0):

Try following.

- npm rm -g create-react-app
- npm install -g create-react-app
- npx create-react-app my-app

[here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088) is a thread that may help too.